# What's Wrong with this Insert Command?

Tags: sql-server, insert

Where is the problem in this statement?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO User_images (Pictures,UserName ) VALUES (@pic1,'" + username.Text + "')(@pic2,'" + username.Text + "')(@pic3,'" + username.Text + "')(@pic4,'" + username.Text + "')(@pic5,'" + username.Text + "')(@pic6,'" + username.Text + "')", con1);
```

The error is:

> incorrect syntax near "

Comment: it looks like you are missing the commas between each set.  e.g. "values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)...."

Comment: You're missing commas, but you should **also** use **parameters** for both values - not just for the first one! This avoids SQL injection attacks - the #1 vulnerability out there on the web!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no commas between each set of entries.  The SQL portion of your statement should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO User_images (Pictures,UserName ) VALUES 
(@pic1,'" + username.Text + "'), --comma
(@pic2,'" + username.Text + "'), --comma
(@pic3,'" + username.Text + "'), --comma
(@pic4,'" + username.Text + "'), --comma
(@pic5,'" + username.Text + "'), --comma
(@pic6,'" + username.Text + "')
```